# Access multiline EditText scrollbar within ScrollView

Tags: android-edittext, scrollview, scrollbar

**I have an EditText multiline that displays a scrollbar when max lines are reached inside a ScrollView**. When I try to scroll the EditText scrollbar, **the ScrollView is scrolled instead**, making it impossible for the user to use the EditText scrollbar. Is there a way to make is possible ?

```
     <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/careInformation"
            android:layout_width="300dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:hint="More information"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:scrollbars="vertical"
            android:maxLines="5"
            android:minLines="1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Nested scroll view](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/core/widget/NestedScrollView) seems like a good answer. It gives focus when you touch it and removes it when you touch any other scrollable view.